# How to get reference to input[type='number'] elements with 0 or certain numeric value using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, filter, numeric

Can this be achieved using a one-liner statement instead of the filter callback function?

Comment: What is the reason for negative vote?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the value attribute

```js
console.log($('input[type="number"][value="0.00"]')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="-1">
<input type="number" value="0.00">
<input type="number" value="1">
```

Comment: What if the actual value is 0.00 or 0.0 or 0? Will it match? I need numeric comparison, not text comparison.

Comment: @Aamir see my sinppet you need the value to be exactly like the value in the input

Comment: of you want to match both you will need something like https://jsfiddle.net/xj676jzo/1/

Comment: Thank you, but that means provisioning for every combination possible. I was hoping for catch all numeric comparison, not text comparison. Thanks for your time though!

Comment: then you need the filter function

Comment: I thought so. Thanks for confirming!